# How to select custom bars using Sibelius?

Tags: sibelius

How could every bar be selected, excluding every 5th bar? I only know how to select from bar __ to bar __ (Select > Select bars) but not how to make a custom selection. Is it possible for this type of function?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "pick 'n mix" selection of objects - individual notes, text items etc.  with Ctrl-click (or the Mac equivalent).  But a passage selection must be a contiguous passage.  So I'm afraid what you want isn't possible.